# what are key values for special characters?

Tags: javascript

```
function alphaOnly(event) {
            var key = event.keyCode;
            return ((key >= 8 && key <= 47) || (key >= 65 && key <= 222));
        };
```

My function is not able to print @ # $ % & ! * ( ) 
I could not find key codes for the above symbols. Please help me to accept these characters.

Comment: Add `console.log(key)` and see for yourself.

Comment: try to use regular expression instead of you used

Comment: Those characters are not alphabetical so calling your function `alphaOnly` is really confusing.

Comment: check ascii value of @, #, $.. etc

Comment: @RahulPawar https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes no key codes for these symbols..

Comment: i am working on the logic..function name does not affect my logic...i will change the function name once i got result @Quentin

Comment: Add console.log(key) and see for yourself - ok i will try ..thank you @Quentin

Comment: @RahulDudharejiya actually i am working on the code written by previous employees...so regulr expression did not work on this..if i did not get key codes for these then i will try with regular expression..thanks for the guidance

Comment: @vaishu check this link https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html for ascii value of all special symbol

Comment: Keycodes are not the same as ascii characters.  When you type a @, you have to press shift + 2, so you would get a keycode for 2 and a flag for shift.  I would suggest not using keyCode to look for special characters, use it to detect presses on specific keyboard keys.

Comment: hai people, i got the result. need to use keypress event instead of keydown/keyup event. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression instead on checking ascii values :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function alphaOnly() {
        var isValid = false;
        var regex = /^[a-zA-Z%*#]*$/;
        isValid = regex.test($("#field").val());
        return isValid;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That won't work unless you first get the character in the form of a string … how do you do that?

Comment: `$` is undefined (the question is not tagged [tag:jquery]. Leaving that aside, this depends on the value being updated before your code runs. This type of code is normally run `onkeydown` so that invalid values can be intercepted **before** updating the value. It doesn't really help if you discover the value being typed is invalid *after* the change has been accepted by the form control: It is too late to block it then.